# how to send email to user after purchase on STRIPE with ruby ​on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments, actionmailer

I would like to know how to send an email to the user after successful checkout

My `Webhook` controller:

```rb
class WebhooksController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token
  
  def create
    payload = request.body.read
    sig_header = request.env['HTTP_STRIPE_SIGNATURE']
    event = nil
  
    begin
      event = Stripe::Webhook.construct_event(
        payload, sig_header, Rails.application.credentials[:stripe][:webhook]
      )
    rescue JSON::ParserError => e
      status 400
      return
    rescue Stripe::SignatureVerificationError => e
      # Invalid signature
      puts "Signature error"
      return
    end
  
    # Handle the event
    case event.type
    when 'checkout.session.completed'
      session = event.data.object
      session_with_expand = Stripe::Checkout::Session.retrieve({id: session.id, expand: ["line_items"] })  
      session_with_expand.line_items.data.each do |line_item| 
      product = Product.find_by(stripe_product_id: line_item.price.product)
      product.increment!(:sales_count)

      end
    end
  
    render json: { message: 'success' }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are creating the payment intent with the Ruby SDK you can add the receipt_email field to add a customers email.(see ther [Stripe PaymentIntent docs](https://stripe.com/docs/receipts#:%7E:text=Stripe%20can%20automatically%20send%20email,customer%27s%20email%20address%20after%20checkout.))

```
Stripe.api_key = 'API_KEY'

intent = Stripe::PaymentIntent.create({
  amount: 1099,
  currency: 'cad',
  payment_method_types: ['card'],
  receipt_email: 'jenny.rosen@example.com',
})
```

If you are creating the checkout session server side you can preconfigure the properties/settings like for the checkout page per the [Stripe Checkout Docs](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create?lang=ruby)

```
require 'stripe'
Stripe.api_key ='API_KEY'

Stripe::Checkout::Session.create({
  success_url: 'https://example.com/success',
  cancel_url: 'https://example.com/cancel',
  customer_email:'email',
  line_items: [
    {price: 'price_H5ggYwtDq4fbrJ', quantity: 2},
  ],
  mode: 'payment',
})
```

This is the note on the customer email field per Stripe docs :

> If provided, this value will be used when the Customer object is
> created. If not provided, customers will be asked to enter their email
> address. Use this parameter to prefill customer data if you already
> have an email on file. To access information about the customer once a
> session is complete, use the customer field.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i would like to know if there is a way to send using the action mailer, because I think the API only sends if it is in production, i'm using test data

Comment: Yes that's correct it will only work in production mode as Stripe won't send emails in test mode. This thread talks about actionmailer with subscriptions/invoices  as an example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20063401/stripe-event-gem-and-action-mailer-for-invoice-webhook

Comment: Thaankss my friend